# install windown7 from usb pen error

Tags: windows-7

I tried to install windows7 from USB according to the instructions of following page.
    http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-install-windows-7vista-from-usb-drive-detailed-100-working-guide/

But at the location where i select the partition it says me something like "device not found."(Cant give the exact machine as i came to somewhere else to search the internet, coz my machine's not working).

How can i overcome this?? I've formatted the whole disk. Got nothing to do now!!!

Comment: Don't ask this kind of questions here next time. go to a relevent forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have formatted the whole hard disk. That is the problem. It's a windows 7 specific problem. I'll describe the case in brief. the setup detects your pen drive as a part of the hard disk(at least something like this). Therefore you can overcome the issue by not letting this to happen.

Which means, you can make the pen drive read only (or make don't allow setup to use pen drives storage). One possible solution will be fill the empty space of the pen drive with bulky data. then there will be no space for the setup program to use in the pen.

Or else you can remove pen drive at the time where the setup is trying to access it (for the above mentioned purpose). How to know the exact time??? well it's trial and error. I myself have done it and it worked. It will require some Patience.

Of course, you can install some other os and then try install win7 after that.

Hope that helps..!!